# How can I draw bigger resolution GLSurfaceView than device's resolution?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm developing a mute camera app using GLSulfaceView, and the app captures a picture from the preview.

For capturing a picture, I use

```
GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, surfaceWidth, surfaceHeight, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);
```

In this time, my picture has the same resolution as the phone's resolution.

For getting the higher resolution picture, I think that the app have to draw higher resolution preview than the device screen resolution fitting the device screen and capture the preview.

How can I draw higher resolution preview than the device screen resolution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glReadPixels` cannot scale an image - you just get a 1:1 read of the current content of the framebuffer.

Use the current image as a texture, and render it to a larger off-screen framebuffer. However note that simple linear filtering (which is all OpenGL ES can give you) isn't going to be particularly high quality upscaling.